# Counting integer points in a Minkowski sum

Tags: discrete-geometry

We have known from Ehrhart theory that if $P$ is a $d$-dimensional polytope of $\mathbb R^n$ which has integer vertices then the number of integer points in $nP$ is a polynomial of degree $d$. We also know the leading coefficients, the second and the constant coefficients.
I wonder if we have a similar conclusion in the case we count the number of integer points in $t_1P_1+...+t_kP_k$ where + denotes Minkowski sum and $P_i$ are polytopes of interger vertices, $t_i\in \mathbb Z$

Comment: Google for "mixed volume"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Proving this is actually problem 3 on page 164 of Integer Points in Polyhedra by Alexander Barvinok - the number of integer points is a polynomial in $t_1,...,t_k$ as long as they are non-negative integers.

Proof omitted at the moment because I'm too rusty to produce one

Comment: Thank you very much. I also have question about the first and the second coefficients of this multivariate polynomial, since we have known them in the case univariate. Could you please explain me a little bit about changing computation of the second coefficients in Ehrhart polynomial from boundary volume to normal vectors on $\mathbb S^n$. It is on the page 56, lemma 3.8 of this dissertation
https://www.google.com.vn/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDEQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.uni-frankfurt.de%2Ffb%2Ffb12%2Fmathematik%2Fdm%2Fpersonen%2Fsteffens%2FDokumente%2FDiss1.pdf&e